# Java Program Not Running

Tags: java, console

I made a factoring program with java. I have a project in eclipse with 2 packages. One has only one class, the one I am having problems with, and the other package has nothing in it.
When I click run, nothing happens and I have no idea why.

Here is the java code:

```
    package com.frostbytedev.factor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class factor {
    static ArrayList<Integer> notFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static int i = 0;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Initialize();
    }

    private static void Initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter a number to factor below:");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = in.nextInt();
        FactorNumber(number);
        PrintList(Factors);
    }

    private static void PrintList(ArrayList<Integer> factorsToPrint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(i=0;i<factorsToPrint.size()-1;i++){
            System.out.print(factorsToPrint.get(i)+", ");
        }
            System.out.print(factorsToPrint.size());

    }

    private static void FactorNumber(int number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(i=2;i<number/2;i++){
            if(number%i==0){
                FactorNumber(i);
                FactorNumber(number/i);
            } else {
                notFactors.add(i);
            }
        }
        if(notFactors.size()==number){
            factors.add(number);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Side note: Please use the [Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm), they will make it easier for those who look at your code to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your Class by right clicking the Class File in your Project Explorer -> Run As... -> Java Application

Comment: Did that but nothing happens

Comment: Actually when I mouse over the run button it says already running but when I click to open the console view nothing happens

Comment: You can switch between the Console Views. In the Console Window there is a button "Display Selected Console". You can terminate them by clicking on the red Button called "terminate". Terminate all Running Programs, then try to run the factor class again by right clicking its file.

Answer (score 0):

There were following errors in the code
   1)There was an infinite loop in your code due to i being static.
   2)factors should be a set to avoid duplicates
   3)if (notFactors.size() == number / 2 - 1) as loop starts with 2.
   4)for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) It should be <=

This does not print 1 & the number itself which are factors too. If you need them you can add to the set.

```
package com.frostbytedev.factor;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
static ArrayList<Integer> notFactors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
static Set<Integer> factors = new HashSet<Integer>();

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Initialize();
}

private static void Initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter a number to factor below:");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    in.close();
    FactorNumber(number);
    PrintList(factors);
}

static void PrintList(Set<Integer> factorsToPrint) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int factor : factorsToPrint) {
        System.out.print(factor + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(factorsToPrint.size());

}

private static void FactorNumber(int number) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (number % i == 0) {
            factors.add(i);
            FactorNumber(i);
            FactorNumber(number / i);
        } else {
            notFactors.add(i);
        }
    }
    if (notFactors.size() == number / 2 - 1) {
        factors.add(number);
    }
};
```

}